# Input to batch file from Jekins Pipeline

Tags: batch-file, jenkins-pipeline

I would i implement:
Input to the batch file from Jenkins Pipeline.
In Below example, values to the Batch file either `Build` or `Test`

Pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
               echo "Build"
                   bat '"excute.bat"'
                }                   
            }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
               echo "Test"
                   bat '"excute.bat"'
                }                   
            }
        }
```

Batch file: excute.bat

```
SET BUILD_OR_TEST= ??
```

Comment: you should be able to set environemnt variables through the jenkins file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could solve the problem:
Updated batch file:

```
@echo off
SET BUILD_OR_TEST=%1
```

Updated Pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
               echo "Build"
                   bat '"excute.bat" BUILD'
                }                   
            }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
               echo "Test"
                   bat '"excute.bat" TEST'
                }                   
            }
        }
```