# Trying to use BAT-Multithreading inside Jenkins (Freestyle Project)

Tags: windows, multithreading, batch-file, jenkins

We are in a migration from Windows Task Scheduler to Jenkins.

We have a Windows BAT file named "processes.bat", containing the following 3 lines.

```bash
start /b cmd /k python my_python_code_01.py
start /b cmd /k python my_python_code_02.py
start /b cmd /k python my_python_code_03.py
```

Each of the 3 lines run concurrently, creating a separate thread for each line (thanks to `start /b`).
This works like a charm when launched from Windows Task Shceduler (or even when simply double click to the BAT file).

But, when we launch the same BAT file from Jenkins it crashes,
that because as soon as one of the 3 processes finishes, then the entire BAT is finished/killed by Jenkins.

May be Jenkins does not support `start /b`, or it should be put using a slightly different syntax?
Or the only way to use concurrency/multithreading (inside one single Build) is using "[paralel()](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/parallelism-and-distributed-builds-jenkins)"?

We would like to take advantage of several BAT files we have already have prepared/tested for Multithreading.

Here some details related to what we tried on Jenkins:

- Jenkins Version 2.414.2
- Type of project used: "Freestyle Project".
- Project Configuration: Build Steps --> Execute Windows batch command --> "D:\some_folder\processes.bat"

We would like to launch the same BAT from Jenkins and take advantage of the Multithreading already coded inside the BAT file.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: I really don't think you need `cmd /k` on each line.

Comment: I am not sure why Jenkins would kill the parent batch file if it sees one of the child processes has finished.  Regardless, this [style of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33586872/1417694) may help with that.

Answer (score 0):

After several tries, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584587/how-to-wait-all-batch-files-to-finish-before-exiting/33586872#33586872) approach, and other found online,
we were not able to make it work: Jenkins + Multitreads (created inside BAT files).

At the end, we migrated the BAT files into:
Jenkins Pipeline Declarative Groovy code.

We took insights from the following links:

- Parallel usage: [link](https://www.incredibuild.com/blog/jenkins-parallel-builds-jenkins-distributed-builds)
- Parameters - External: Jenkins web app to Groovy: [link](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/jenkins-parameterized-builds)
- Conditional "when" and using "local" ENV variables: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358652/jenkinsfile-define-variable-based-on-environment-variable)
- Pipeline local Functions: [link](https://naiveskill.com/jenkins-pipeline-functions/)
- Pass args/params from Groovy to BAT: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68130199/input-to-batch-file-from-jekins-pipeline)
- BAT - reading received args/params: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/932408/how-to-receive-a-parameter-in-a-batch-file)

Regards.